# Iterate all the charts in a workbook and automatic add count number to the nearest top left cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

For some reason I have to add 200+ figure number to my excel chart pack.
The file structure is like this...

```
Sheet1(1 figure)
Sheet2(3 figures)
Sheet3(20 figures)
....
Sheet99(1 figure)
```

All sheets are not overlayed with each other.
And they are apart from original data in the same sheet.
I need to find a way to locate the nearest top left cell of each chart,
And insert value like `= Figure.x` (x=counter of the figure number) automatically.

Answer (score 1):

is this ok ?

```
Dim oWs As Worksheet
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim iShape As Integer

iShape = 0
For Each oWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each oShape In oWs.Shapes
        iShape = iShape + 1
        oShape.TopLeftCell.Value = "Figure." & iShape
    Next
Next
```